# trying to run a sequence of numbers for a function i defined. but it only returns one sample instead of 500

Tags: r, loops

```
Y = function(N, mu, sigma){
  sample = exp(rnorm(N, mu, sigma))
  return(sample)
}

mu_range = seq(0, 5, by = 0.01)
for (i in mu_range){
  sample_mu = Y(10, i, 2)
  return(sample_mu)
}
```

I need to generate samples from the log-normal distribution for a number of different values for μ in the range (0, 5)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using a `return` statement if you're not writing a function, so in this case, the `return(sample_mu)` is not needed in your for loop. You also need something to store your generated samples in. One quick modification you can do is as follows:

```
Y = function(N, mu, sigma){
  sample = exp(rnorm(N, mu, sigma))
  return(sample)
}

mu_range = seq(0, 5, by = 0.01)
sample_mus = array(NA, dim=c(10,length(mu_range)))
for (i in 1:length(mu_range)){
  sample_mus[,i] = Y(10, i, 2)
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use `sapply` to write this in a single line as:

```
Y = function(N, mu, sigma){
  sample = exp(rnorm(N, mu, sigma))
  return(sample)
}

sample_mus = sapply(seq(0, 5, by = 0.01),function(i) Y(10, i, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've just started coding and really struggle with the language, so I really appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help :)